# How to use InputMethodManager.showSoftInput() in Password EditText Field

Tags: java, android

I can't use `inputMethodManager.showSoftInput()` method in Password `EditText` field. But I can use this method in Username `EditText`. I find the difference between Username and Password `edittext` is NAF is True for Password.

Is there is any way to use `inputMethodManager.showSoftInput()` in password `EditText`?

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you trying? it is not clear yet

Comment: Sorry for delay . Using inputmethodmanager i have decided whether keyboard is visible or not when click username edittext . The same way i was trying to check in password edittext . But password edittext is NAF true . So i can't use inputmethod manager in password edittext .